# What's the meaning of "institute" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a passage from an [article](http://www.omg-facts.com/Interesting/If-You-re-Ever-Selected-To-Get-A-Star-On/59095) on The Hollywood Walk of Fame:

> However, receiving a star on the famed walk isn't all, well, receiving. It turns out it actually costs you money. Or at least it costs the person or entity nominating you.
>
> This fee was **instituted** in 1980 at $2,500 to fund the walk's upkeep and minimize taxpayer burden. As of 2012, this fee had reached $30,000.

I've looked up the word on Dictionary.com and it seems there are several definitions(def.1-4) that could fit the context, but is there a specific one that's most appropriate? The definitions of *institute* from Dictionary.com are:

> verb (used with object)
>   1. to set up; establish; organize: to institute a government.
>   2. to inaugurate; initiate; start: to institute a new course in American literature.
>   3. to set in operation: to institute a lawsuit.
>   4. to bring into use or practice: to institute laws.
>   5. to establish in an office or position.
>   6. Ecclesiastical . to assign to or invest with a spiritual charge, as of a parish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four of those seem pretty similar. I'd pick 2 if I really had to choose, but I think the general definition from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institute is best:

> to begin or create (something, such as a new law, rule, or system)

Comment: The meanings of dictionary definitions often overlap. Unless you've taking a test where the problem is to pick the right definition, I wouldn't worry about picking exactly which of several very similar dictionary definitions applies.